# Add json inner object

Tags: java, json

I have the following code

```
JSONArray jobj = new select_data().get_patient_summary(p_id);
JSONObject jInnerObject = new JSONObject();
jInnerObject.put("weight", weight.get(0));
jobj.put(jInnerObject);
```

The outcome is:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "pre_transfusional_haemoglobin_level": "",
            "rhesus_blood_group_system": "",
            "patient_id": "1",
            "surname": "Demetriou",
            "DOB": "2004-02-04",
            "health_insurance_information": "ac",
            "name": "Andreas",
            "blood_group": "",
            "transfusion_frequency": ""
        },
        {
            "weight": "90"
        }
    ],
    "success": 1
}
```

Can I insert "weight" in the previous string, like:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "pre_transfusional_haemoglobin_level": "",
            "rhesus_blood_group_system": "",
            "patient_id": "1",
            "surname": "Demetriou",
            "DOB": "2004-02-04",
            "health_insurance_information": "ac",
            "name": "Andreas",
            "blood_group": "",
            "transfusion_frequency": "",
            "weight": "90"
        },
    ],
    "success": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED for complete executable code:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String input = "{\r\n" + 
                "    \"data\": [\r\n" + 
                "        {\r\n" + 
                "            \"pre_transfusional_haemoglobin_level\": \"\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"rhesus_blood_group_system\": \"\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"patient_id\": \"1\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"surname\": \"Demetriou\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"DOB\": \"2004-02-04\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"health_insurance_information\": \"ac\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"name\": \"Andreas\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"blood_group\": \"\",\r\n" + 
                "            \"transfusion_frequency\": \"\"\r\n" + 
                "        },\r\n" +
                "    ],\r\n" + 
                "    \"success\": 1\r\n" + 
                "}";
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(input);
        jobj.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(0).put("weight", 90);
        System.out.println(jobj.toString(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, `jobj` is `JSONArray` and not `JSONObject`. I'm not the one who added downvote.

Comment: Yeah, you can change the variable name if ```jobj``` can not be used. In case it solves your problem please accept it as an answer. I'm sort of in a rush.. :)